# How can you reliably track CSS usages?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

My environment is Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper 6.0.  I have a large website with many CSS files with many styles.

I would like to tidy these up as a lot of them are no longer used, I noticed that Resharper allows you to track usages but obviously this can miss out CSS class specifications in code-behind etc.

My only solution is to do a Find In Files in VS but obviously when you have a large amount of styles this proves too slow and cumbersome.

Has anyone had a similar predicament?

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that the site is a CMS comprising around 10,000 pages, so anything that requires browsing pages might also be a bit tricky.

Comment: Upvoting and favoriting. Hope someone knows of a good tool! :D

Answer (score 3):

There is a [firefox](http://firefox.com) extension called [dust me selector](http://www.sitepointstatic.com/dustmeselectors/) that does this. You enable it and then navigate to each page. It keeps track of all used css. You spit out a new css file with all the tracked css styles.

Comment: Too bad it's not supported for ff 7. :(

Comment: I see your problem. I would hope there is a solution out there that just hits every page and looks at the styles. Let's see what others say. I would love to start the open source project. :)

Comment: When you factor in things like server-side and client-side changes to classes it could be tricky to nail down every element, but you could aim for around 90% of them I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink) Visual Studio Extension has a BrowserLink feature which comes with a way to track unused css in your site while you browse around the site.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I would like to separate the CSS entries in multiple files. Webessential can help in this?

Comment: @coma: I'm trying to use it, seems interesting.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do that is running your site in a headless browser like PhantomJS and inspecting the styles applied in order to remove the ones not being used.

Fortunately, there is a nice tool built on node called **uncss** doing exactly this:

https://github.com/giakki/uncss

I found it here:

http://addyosmani.com/blog/removing-unused-css/

About browsing all those pages, well, I dunno, if you can generate all the possible URL's then you can automate the process.

Give it a try and let me know if it helps.